# Onclick div only works for one user

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mybb

I am using this code on my forum postbit. I am trying to have a *div* element reveal some text for each user but I can only get it working for the first user.

The other divs are always open. I am not sure where I'm going wrong with it.

```js
function toggleDiv(id) {
  $("#" + myContent).toggle();
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="javascript:toggleDiv('myContent');">
  <i style="color: #000; font-size: 13px;" class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-fw"></i>
</a>
<div class="animated fadeIn" id="myContent" style="padding: 10px;">
  Reveal text here.
</div>
```

Comment: Is it supposed to toggle on an event? or do you just want it to fade in when the page loads?

Comment: Toggle on event but separately for each user.

Comment: @andreas, what do you mean when you say the first user?

Answer (score 2):

Don't you mean `$("#" + id).toggle();` ?

If you look at the console, you will see an error message saying that `myContent` is undefined.

You cannot concatenate a String (`'#'`) with an `undefined` variable in JavaScript.

```js
function toggleDiv(id) {
  $("#" + id).toggle();
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="javascript:toggleDiv('myContent');">
  <i style="color: #000; font-size: 13px;" class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-fw"></i>
</a>
<div class="animated fadeIn" id="myContent" style="padding: 10px;">
  Reveal text here.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of changes here:

1. Add the [jQuery](https://jquery.org/) source. Add this script tag above your script tag:
   `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`
    
   **Note**: *it appears Mr. Polywhirl has added this to your sample.*
2. Utilize the *id* parameter in function *toggleDiv()* 
   i.e. `$("#"+id).toggle();`, unless *myContent* is defined elsewhere, it will be *undefined* so `$("#" + myContent).toggle();` will cause an error.
3. To have the content initially hidden, add the style `display: none`.
4. Remove the *fadeIn* class name initially and add it after toggling the element using [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).

See the updated example below.

As far as when to show the message for the *first user*, we need to know what your business logic is for that concept. Can you tell what the *pid* (or *uid*, given [this list of fields in their API for posts](https://docs.mybb.com/1.6/Database-Tables-mybb-posts/)) value is of the first user, perhaps based on a given list of posts in MyBB? You mention that this code is at the top of the page: `<a name="pid{$post['pid']}" id="pid{$post['pid']}"></a>`. So if you knew a certain *pid* value (e.g. 1337) you could conditionally add the code to add the message to the DOM - e.g.

```
$html = '';
if ($post['pid'] == 1337) {
     $html .= '<a href="javascript:toggleDiv(\'myContent\');">';
}
//add $html to the rest of the HTML outputted to the page
```

```js
function toggleDiv(id) {
  $("#" + id).toggle().toggleClass('fadeIn');
}
```

```css
.animated {  
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
    -o-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
    transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
}
.fadeIn {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<a href="javascript:toggleDiv('myContent');"><i style="color: #000; font-size: 13px;" class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-fw"></i></a>
<div class="animated" id="myContent" style="padding: 10px; display: none">
  reveal text here
</div>
```

Comment: They all work perfect but still the same problem where it only works for the first user.  I am using MyBB forum software.

Comment: I was about to ask something about what distinguishes the _first user_ above (on the question)

Comment: Added it there.

Comment: I'm not sure but it has these at the top of the page.  

<a name="pid{$post['pid']}" id="pid{$post['pid']}"></a>

Comment: Please update your original post to include more information, e.g. information about that code, plugins used, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your function takes a parameter **id**, but you're using **myContent** i the body of the function. Like this it works:

```js
function toggleDiv(id) {
   $("#"+id).toggle();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="javascript:toggleDiv('myContent');"><i style="color: #000; font-size: 13px;" class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-fw">icon here</i></a>



<div class="animated fadeIn" id="myContent" style="padding: 10px;">
reveal text here
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure how to edit my first post but here is a pasteit of the postbit template without my code added.

https://justpaste.it/11by4

Answer (score 0):

You are using `myContent` instead of `id` inside the function, replace that and it should work:

```js
function toggleDiv(id) {
  $("#" + id).toggle();
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:toggleDiv('myContent');">
  <i style="color: #000; font-size: 13px;" class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-fw"></i>
</a>
<div class="animated fadeIn" id="myContent" style="padding: 10px;">
  Reveal text here.
</div>
```